# Google Groups service returned 404 error

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-groups

I tried to use Google group service inside my website though embedding this code inside the home page, But it returned 404 error! Is it because I'm using localhost ?

```
<iframe id="forum_embed"
  src="javascript:void(0)"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  width="900"
  height="700">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('forum_embed').src =
     'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/*********'
     + '&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false'
     + '&parenturl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
</script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate about what you mean by "using localhost"? Your code is almost identical to the [Google Support Example](http://support.google.com/groups/answer/1191206?hl=en), so unless the forum name you're targetting does not exist (or is closed to you), I'd expect it to work.

Comment: @Mogsdad, `locahost` just means "[this computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)".  It's the hostname developers use to point to their own machine instead of having to type out their IP address.

Comment: @DemPilafian, yes, that's what localhost means. But you'll note I asked what the OP meant by "USING localhost". Since `localhost` doesn't appear in their code, the question is unclear. FWIW, the example works for me, on my "localhost" - apache on linux, so there's something more to this. But thank you for pointing out the existence of wikipedia, that will make life much easier for me. </sarcasm>

Comment: @Mogsdad, Of course `localhost` does not appear in the code.  I think you're confused.  The OP made it pretty clear he was running on his development machine.  Anyway, your `</sarcasm>` tag is invalid as it's not paired with an opening tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the 404 problem is because you are running from `localhost`.  I use the built-in Apache server on Mac OS X and encountered exactly the same issue.  Once I uploaded the HTML files to my hosted website, the Google Groups forum displayed properly.